# How to create a new column based on the mean difference between date columns in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame formatted like so (I simplified it for the sake of my explanation):

| Date_1 | Date_2 | Date_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-02-14 | 2017-02-09 | 2017-02-10 |
| 2018-07-16 | 2019-07-22 | 2018-07-16 |
| 2014-10-10 | 2017-10-10 | 2017-10-10 |

I would like to create a new column that shows the average difference between my date columns. Specifically, I would like it to calculate the difference between Date_1 & Date_2, Date_2 & Date_3, and Date_1 & Date_3. In row # 1 that would equal mean(5 + 1 + 4) = 3.33.

The data frame would look something like this:

| Date_1 | Date_2 | Date_3 | Average_Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-02-14 | 2017-02-09 | 2017-02-10 | 3.33 |
| 2018-07-16 | 2019-07-22 | 2018-07-16 | mean(6+6+0) = 4 |
| 2014-10-10 | 2017-10-10 | 2017-10-10 | 0 |

Do let me know if further explanation is needed.

Edit: I should also add that my actual, un-simplified dataframe has more than just three date columns, so I am trying to think of an answer that is scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. Since you're getting the diffs of several items in each row, `itertools.combinations(iterable, N)` will help. It returns all a possible `N`-length combinations of the items in `iterable`. So we can use that for each row, diff each combination, absolute it (since some might be negative because of the sorting), and compute the mean:

```
date_cols = df.filter(like='Date_').columns
df[date_cols] = df[date_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime) # Convert the columns to dates
df['Average_Difference'] = df[date_cols].apply(lambda row: np.mean([diff for diff in abs(np.diff(list(it.combinations([date.dayofyear for date in row], 2)))[:, 0])]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      Date_1     Date_2     Date_3  Average_Difference
0 2017-02-14 2017-02-09 2017-02-10            3.333333
1 2018-07-16 2019-07-22 2018-07-16            4.000000
2 2014-10-10 2017-10-10 2017-10-10            0.000000
```

Comment: I am struggling to implement your solution, would you mind breaking it down a little more for me? Specifically, I keep getting the following error : "'str' object has no attribute 'dayofyear'" and I cannot figure it out. Many thanks

Comment: Oops! That's my fault. Fix coming...

Comment: I added an extra line. Check now, @Mitchell.

Comment: Basically what is does is, for each row, it gets the day-of-year of each date, and creates as many 2-item pairs out of them as possible. Then, for each pair, it subtracts the first item from the second, and makes the positive in case the subtraction goes the wrong way. Then it just computes the mean of the resulting diffs and adds them to the `Average_Difference` column. It does this for each row.